# how to make the cmd window go away when running a system command in c++

Tags: visual-c++, system, cmd, mkdir

I am using c++.NET and my program needs to make a directory

I normally do this with the system command

```
system("mkdir");
```

but when I do this command in my gui program this cmd window comes in and disapears again is there any way to do the command without that window showing up?

or is there a easier way to make a directory in c++?

### thanks

luck

Comment: Why would you do this instead of using the appropriate API call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CreateDirectory ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363855%28VS.85%29.aspx ) is an easier way, though you have to create any intermediate directories yourself.

Alternatively you can use CreateProcess to launch a console with the flag CREATE_NO_WINDOW (and remember to wait for the process to terminate).

Comment: This is a native Win32 API call. The asker has stated that they are using C++.NET, therefore it is better to use something from the FCL.

Comment: okay then, System.io::Directory.CreateDirectory http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.createdirectory%28v=VS.71%29.aspx

which has the advantage of creating intermediate directories